# Is it possible to call addJavascriptInterface on a WebView created by onCreateWindow?

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium, webviewclient

I have a simple browser app, my `onCreateWindow` looks like this:

```
if (userGesture) {
            WebView childView = new WebView(webBrowserActivity);
            WebSettings settings = childView.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setSupportZoom(true);
            settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            childView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyInterface(),"NAME");
            <--- code in here to add the view to a ViewPager.
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(childView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            Log.v(TAG, "Opening popup for " + childView.getUrl());
            webBrowserActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

I have tried adding this interface a bit later down the line, I have also tried calling `reload()` or `loadUrl()` after the page is loaded because the documentation says the javascript interface must be added prior to loading the page. None of this has helped. Has anyone done this successfully?

Thanks.

EDIT: I should mention I see this more on 4.4, I am using the desktop debugger for Chrome and I can go into the console and see the `window.NAME` object on the first webview and not on the second one. On 4.3 it seems to work fairly often.

I edited the code above to show the settings I am using. The javascript interface I am adding to the WebView works just fine when added to the first WebView that gets created when the Activity starts.

Comment: Which version of Android are you using?

Comment: On 4.4 I know for sure that is what is happening because I can attach with the desktop Chrome to debug the mobile browser. On 4.3 I get the same issue but only on some popups but because I can't easily debug I have no idea what is really happening there.

Comment: I just played with it for a bit longer on 4.3 and it seems to work pretty much always there, must be an issue with the new 4.4 changes.

Comment: Can you keep a reference to the child view and add the javascript *after* you've sent the resultMsg back? I think that sendToTarget will run asynchronously, so doing it immediately afterwards might not be enough.

Comment: I've tried doing that, I've tried refreshing the page and readding the interface, loading a new url, no matter what I try, if the WebView was created using onCreateWindow it just won't work. I do have a nasty workaround where I create a new WebView and use the same url, that works just fine.

Comment: @casolorz I am facing the same issue. Can you share the workaround you got of creating new webview using URL.

Comment: Sorry I totally moved away from using javascript interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a bug in the KitKat WebView that makes it impossible to register a JavaScript interface on the popup window. There is no known workaround for the issue I'm afraid, other than as you suggest, keep the URL for the popup, return false from onCreateWindow and then create a whole new webview and load the pop up URL into it.

Comment: This is **not a bug** and there's a workaround. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25752323/1489493)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It should work. I hope you did this:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Yes I am doing that, sorry I forgot to copy that piece of code when making the post. I should also have mentioned I have zero issues with this on the first WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem using JS after webview created by onCreateWindow.
After digging sources, I feel like it's impossible.

```
final WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) msg.obj;
if(transport!=null){
    transport.setWebView(mCustomWebView);
}
msg.sendToTarget();
```

After we send a message to target, [WebViewChromium](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/webview/+/idea133/chromium/java/com/android/webview/chromium/WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java) do this

```
        mUiThreadHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what) {
                case NEW_WEBVIEW_CREATED:
                    WebView.WebViewTransport t = (WebView.WebViewTransport) msg.obj;
                    WebView newWebView = t.getWebView();
                    if (newWebView == mWebView) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                "Parent WebView cannot host it's own popup window. Please " +
                                "use WebSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false)");
                    }

                    if (newWebView != null && newWebView.copyBackForwardList().getSize() != 0) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                "New WebView for popup window must not have been previously " +
                                "navigated.");
                    }

                    **WebViewChromium.completeWindowCreation(mWebView, newWebView);**
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }
```

Then, it reads to [addPossiblyUnsafeJavascriptInterface](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/c02a6f51a172c21c0652e69cd5bf503b97990d9b/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/ContentViewCore.java).

```
public void addPossiblyUnsafeJavascriptInterface(Object object, String name,
        Class<? extends Annotation> requiredAnnotation) {
    if (mNativeContentViewCore != 0 && object != null) {
        mJavaScriptInterfaces.put(name, object);
        nativeAddJavascriptInterface(mNativeContentViewCore, object, name, requiredAnnotation,
                mRetainedJavaScriptObjects);
    }
}
```

**It seems like adding JS on an webview by onCreateWindow is prevented for the security reasons.**

The comment says

> /**
>        * This method injects the supplied Java object into the ContentViewCore.
>        * The object is injected into the JavaScript context of the main frame,
>        * using the supplied name. This allows the Java object to be accessed from
>        * JavaScript. Note that that injected objects will not appear in
>        * JavaScript until the page is next (re)loaded. For example:
>        *
>
> ```
>  view.addJavascriptInterface(new Object(), "injectedObject");
>      * view.loadData("", "text/html", null);
>      * view.loadUrl("javascript:alert(injectedObject.toString())");
> ```
>
> *
>
> **IMPORTANT:**
>        *
>
>   *
> - addJavascriptInterface() can be used to allow JavaScript to control
>          * the host application. This is a powerful feature, but also presents a
>          * security risk. Use of this method in a ContentViewCore containing
>          * untrusted content could allow an attacker to manipulate the host
>          * application in unintended ways, executing Java code with the permissions
>          * of the host application. Use extreme care when using this method in a
>          * ContentViewCore which could contain untrusted content. Particular care
>          * should be taken to avoid unintentional access to inherited methods, such
>          * as {@link Object#getClass()}. To prevent access to inherited methods,
>          * pass an annotation for {@code requiredAnnotation}.  This will ensure
>          * that only methods with {@code requiredAnnotation} are exposed to the
>          * Javascript layer.  {@code requiredAnnotation} will be passed to all
>          * subsequently injected Java objects if any methods return an object.  This
>          * means the same restrictions (or lack thereof) will apply.  Alternatively,
>          * {@link #addJavascriptInterface(Object, String)} can be called, which
>          * automatically uses the {@link JavascriptInterface} annotation.
>          *
>
>   JavaScript interacts with Java objects on a private, background
>          * thread of the ContentViewCore. Care is therefore required to maintain
>          * thread safety.
>
>   *

There is a dilemma. You can use JS by getting an url from an webview created onCreateWindow and creating new webview with the url. I tried and it worked when link is simple Hyperlink. But with that way some pages, especially opened by javascript, won't work rightly.

So far I got this and I'm short of time. Please someone shares more. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

The method [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) has a security warning:

> For applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above, only
>   public methods that are annotated with JavascriptInterface can be
>   accessed from JavaScript.

So, if you really need it your code should look like that:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void yourJavaFunction() 
{
    //do you stuff
}
```

Please note that by doing that you're exposed to a **security risk**, as explained in the [note](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: Felling sorry for giving not usefull vote. 
I have same problem with @JavascriptInterface notation.
A custom webview created by activity or fragment is working well with JS.
A Problem comes when webview created by onCreateWindow.